# defining private variables/properties in c++ class

Tags: c++, class

So I've discovered something to do with defining private variables in a class.

At the moment, my Apple.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef Apples_h
#define Apples_h

class Apples {
    public:
        Apples();
        void eat();
        void peel();
        void slice();

    private:
        int _seeds;
        String _type; // originally int by mistake
};

#endif
```

My Apple.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "Apples.h"

int _seeds = 0; // default
String _type = 0; // default

Apples::Apples(){
    _seeds = 5000;
    _type = "notYummy";
}

// pretend all the public methods are implemented and are fine (no issues with them)
```

This actually works fine: I have defined a private property _seeds in my header and .cpp file.

The problem arises when I define a property _seeds somewhere else, say in a parent class/main file.

It then complains that there are multiple definitions of it. To me, this is a bit strange as I am thinking that the _seeds property inside Apple.cpp should be private (and thus unknown), but it somehow picks it up and clashes in another file.

I looked for an example of making classes, and they had it where they did not define the class properties inside the .cpp file, but only in the header file and it just seems to magically creates those private properties in the .cpp file (they aren't defined anywhere in the .cpp file).

My "closest" language is probably Java and for there I define all the class variables/properties in the class implementation file, so I'm a bit confused.

Can anyone confirm that:

1. This is not the case for c/c++ and that you should only define private properties in the header file.
2. any variables/properties inside the class .cpp file are some how in a 'global namespace' where they can collide in other files.

And that if the second point is true, could they be actually accessed by just calling _seeds in another class/file?

(It probably doesn't matter as I think this is just a language thing, but this is code for an arduino.)

Comment: This sounds impossible to me. The properties in the class are confined to the class. Can you post your code?

Comment: TL;DR: should `_type` be an `int` or a `string`?

Comment: Please don't prefix your variable names with an underscore - `Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace`

Comment: Uh, yes whoops. int should be a String. But that wasn't the issue.  >.> Hm, I thought it was a convention to use underscores for private properties? You're saying that underscored names are always in the global namespace?

Comment: @Constantin They're only reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, and in the above example the two variables in "My Apple.cpp" are in global namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining two global variables newly, if you write them outside the class:

```
int _seeds = 0; // default
String _type = 0; // default
```

You just need to initialize the non-static member variables in the ctor as you did.

Comment: in the "ctor" ? If that means .cpp file then I guess point 1 is correct then: only define in header, and only initialize in .cpp file ?

Comment: oh, "constructor". Didn't think to look it up until a few mins after. =/

Comment: @mitim The member variables are defined inside the class defination, and used (initialized) inside the class scope, including member functions (and constructors). Anyway you can't use them in the global scope directly.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I'm still used to java (where I only have one file not two). I'm assuming that "class definition" is header file and "class scope" is my cpp file. Seems like this is it. Thanks. Now I have a bunch of work to do fixing my mistakes in my actual code. >.>

Answer (score 1):

You **must** declare **all** properties and methods of a class in one place in C++. The conventional way is to do it in header file, so all files which include that header file can use the class (they need the full declaration to do so!). However, a class declaration in `.cpp` file is also valid but such a class will be available in that `.cpp` file only.

Your code

```
int _seeds = 0; // default
String _type = 0; // default
```

has **no relation** to the class. This is simply a definition of two global variables. The only way you can set initial values of non-static properties is in constructor, the way you’ve done it in the question looks correct (assuming you declare `Apples::_type` with a string type instead of `int`).

Comment: Right. Someone else mentioned it in the answer, but you've confirmed it again and my second point as well. Thanks. And yes, you're right again, that the int should be a string for _type. A typo that I'd normally edit my question and fix, but then might leave someone else in the future wondering what it was referring to.

Comment: @mitim I would definitely edit the property type in the question and leave a hint in a comment (for example `String _type; // originally int by mistake`). A good question should address one problem, otherwise it becomes cluttered.